# Compare to object angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a problem with AngularJS I receive from API JSON that JSON  contains a prod URL and URL prerpod I would make calls to these APIs to retrieve a new one JSON then compare the results to validate which are the same as the problem is that I have a 200 API test how can I do.
PS: I think the test objects with the method equals.

I have 100 object like this:

```
{
    "ID": "1",
    "URL_preprod": "url1",
    "Preprod_bis": "url2",
    "prod": "url3",
}
```

i need to check if the result of call is equals for each object.

```
  function callAtTimeout() {
   if ($scope.preprod && $scope.preprodBis) {
      angular.equals($scope.preprod,$scope.preprodBis);
      $scope.msg = "equals";
      }}



   $scope.test = function() {
 if (tnrArray) {
 for (var i = 0; i < tnrArray.length; i++) {

  var urlPreprod = tnrArray[i].URL_preprod;
    console.log(urlPreprod);
  $http.get(urlPreprod).success( function(response) {
    $scope.preprod = response;
    console.log(response);
   });

   var urlPreprodBis = tnrArray[i].Preprod_bis;
   console.log(urlPreprodBis);
   $http.get(urlPreprodBis).success( function(response) {
     $scope.preprodBis = response;
     console.log(response);
    });
     $timeout(callAtTimeout, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var response1;

$http.get("/your/url").then(function(response) {
    response1 = response;
    return $http.get(response.prodUrl);
}).then(function(prodResponse) {
    console.log(prodResponse);
    console.log(_.isEqual(response1 , prodResponse));  // uses lodash
}).catch(function(badResponse) {
    console.log("oops something went wrong", badResponse);
})
```

this should work - lodash is used to check for equality

TO DO THIS FOR 200 URLs ASYNCHRONOUSLY ...

```
var urlList = ['/path/url1','/path/url2','/path/url3'];

angular.forEach(urlList, function(url) {

    var response1;

    $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        response1 = response;
        return $http.get(response.prodUrl);
    }).then(function(prodResponse) {
        console.log(prodResponse);
        console.log(angular.equals(response1 , prodResponse));
    }).catch(function(badResponse) {
        console.log("oops something went wrong", badResponse);
    })
});
```

Comment: better to use built in `angular.equals()` which won't compare properties added internally by angular

Comment: how i can make this for 200  url ?

Comment: updated answer see above, note this will do it asynchronously. if you need it done synchronously or in some other way you need to explain more what you need.